# Has the Batmobile ever gotten stuck in a traffic jam?

Tags: dc, batman

Has the Batmobile ever gotten stuck in a traffic jam?

I suppose the Dark Knight will just leave it there in the case of an emergency (perhaps causing more trouble by parking that monster in the middle of the street), but looking for more data on this question I came across [this article](https://www.fortressofsolitude.co.za/batmobile-comic-books-dumbest-gadget/), that mentions a case where the Batmobile self-drove to a specific location in order to save Batman from a fall, which will worsen the situation if it doesn't make it in time.

So... is there any mention in the comics or TV of the Batmobile getting stuck in a traffic jam or a complication derived from this that Batman had to solve? I don't remember all of the Batman TV Series from the 60's but I think that if the situation ever happened it was probably there...

Take into account that I'm also mentioning the self-driving feature of the Batmobile, so your answer can include a situation where Batman is not around.

Comment: The batmobile (and driver) isn't exactly the greatest respecter of traffic laws or roads.

Comment: You mean it just goes over the cars like a Monster truck? Got any reference of it in Batman-related media?

Comment: I've found references to it happening in the Keaton *Batman* film right before Joker attacks Batman and Vale the first time.

Comment: It carries traffic repellent bat-spray.

Comment: Ah, never mind. It just plain got stuck. "After it completely outmatched the Goons' and the GCPD for pure speed, the Batmobile unfortunately was caught in a bottleneck. With the road blocked by a construction crew, Batman and Vicki abandoned the Batmobile and continued their escape. "

Comment: In most of the Batman comic books in my collection, Batman only seems to use the Batmobile to drive through downtown Gotham when it's *late at night* -- i.e. well after most people have gone home from their day jobs, and so "rush hour" has already passed and the streets are less crowded. But I want to think about this some more.

Comment: It's funny, because what FuzzyBoots said could definitely be an answer.

Comment: I read somewhere that the batmobile did get stuck in a traffic jam in the animated series "Beware The Batman", though they didn't mention in which episode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Traffic doesn't slow Batman down much.

In *Detective Comics* #449, he gets stuck behind livestock:

[image: Batman on his radio stuck behind a herd in the Batmobile]

To cope with this, he gets out of his Batmobile and rides a horse instead:

[image: Batman gets on a horse to get through the herd and helps round the horses up]

Similarly, in the Batman '66 comic [*Mr. Freeze Breaks the Ice*](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/batman-66-27-mr-freeze-breaks-the-ice/4000-444755/) the Batmobile gets stuck in snow. Instead of shoveling it out, Batman and Robin don skis and that's how they get around the city.

The book [*Summer Freeze!*](https://books.google.com/books?id=r0rmBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq="Batman+weaves+around".) (with a plot that's basically the same as the comic I just mentioned) has him swerving around cars:

> The freak blizzard has struck Gotham City unprepared, and many motorists have either stranded their cars or found themselves stuck in traffic. Batman weaves around them carefully, but the ice cream truck has no problem driving up on sidewalks, narrowly missing frigid pedestrians wearing T-shirts and flip-flops.

Comment: This is the closest what I asked. And I can't believe that other writers couldn't think of this. Before accepting your answer I'll let one more, just to see if someone found something else.

Comment: I thought Batmobile could fly.. What if he couldn't get a horse?

Answer (score 1):

In *Batman: The Brave And The Bold* , ["Enter The Outsiders!"](https://braveandbold.fandom.com/wiki/Enter_the_Outsiders!), Batman and Wildcat chase the Outsiders through Gotham and the Outsiders then go into a subway (train station) and Wildcat already has a bike which he uses to enter the train station, while "Batman" has his normal vehicle which after having friendly competition and exchanging words in a playful sense of who will reach the outsiders first Batman converts his Batmobile into a Batcycle.

> Wildcat follows on his motorcycle and follows them down into the subway, but Batman switches to Batcycle mode and the two heroes go underground."

So Batman has other ways in which he can bypass traffic in a hurry.

Comment: Nice try, but my question was not about the means of solving the situation.

Answer (score 0):

This clip from *Tiny Toon Adventures* is closest literal example of the Batmobile being stuck in traffic.  The moment begins soon after the 3:50 mark.

I put forth the theory that since we're seeing this done in a cartoon gag/parody implies the incident is such a ludicrously remote probability that it is funny.  If it happened often enough in the actual Batman comics, it'd lose that whackadoodle element.

Comment: This is just a comedy video..

Comment: The situation is indeed funny, because it's a more realistic view. And even if it was making a reference to actual comics, it would still be funny, since not everyone is aware of every single Batman comic. Even more in the Tiny Toons era, when the internet wast just an infant. The only problem is that this is not Batman related media.

Comment: The video link is dead.